# How to detect JS frameworks/libraries used in a page?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom, backbone.js, reactjs

I'd like to be able to detect all the frameworks/libraries used by a page, to help understand when content is dynamically-generated etc.

I downloaded and unpacked the source for two Chrome extensions, [Library Detector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/library-detector/cgaocdmhkmfnkdkbnckgmpopcbpaaejo?hl=en) and [Appspector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/appspector/homgcnaoacgigpkkljjjekpignblkeae?hl=en). It looks like they simply call `window.FUNCTION_NAME_HERE`, for example:

```
'Backbone.js': function () {
  return window.Backbone && typeof(window.Backbone.sync) === 'function';
},
'Underscore.js': function () {
  return window._ && typeof(window._.identity) === 'function' &&
    window._.identity('abc') === 'abc';
},
'Spine': function () {
  return window.Spine;
},
'Angular': function () {
  return window.angular;
},
'Ning': function () {
  return window.ning;
},
'Zepto': function () {
  return window.Zepto;
}
```

etc.

I have a few questions:

1. What are the identifiers for each framework (e.g. "Spine", "angular") called? Is there any way to retrieve this information via AJAX or otherwise, so I don't have to manually enter them?
2. I don't really understand what `window.angular` means, besides that it returns either the angular object or None. I know that AngularJS has loaded if the angular function is accessible through the window object, but I'm not really sure what it even means to be a member function of the window.
3. Why is the procedure for Backbone and Underscore different than all the others? How do you know which one to use?
4. I tried running both extensions on the Uber homepage, which uses React, and neither of them detected React. When I tried to `console.log(window)`, there wasn't a React object listed either. Why is this, and how can I still detect the framework in these cases?

Comment: Your code expects the libraries were exported to the global space, which is not necessary to be the case. And these days with bundlers it's likely to be not the case.

Comment: "Why is this, and how can I still detect the framework in these cases?" --- automatically it's unlikely you can, at least easily and reliably.

Comment: While I could see the usefulness of this goal, I'm very much unsure if there is actually a simple way you could detect the presence of most of these libraries. Javascript libraries can now be "present" in a lot of different ways compared to before. Admittedly, doing this as a browser extension may provide some analysis capabilities a normal page script wouldn't have.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like you have misunderstood how that code detecting libraries work, and of course that relates to understanding the `window` object.

In a browser javascript environment `window` is the global object. All variables are defined as properties of the global `window` object, unless they are defined within a function with the `var` keyword.

Let's say you visit a page that uses jQuery library, open the browser console and type `jQuery`. That should respond with a function, which jQuery is. Essentially `jQuery` is a variable defined in the global scope, and it is available as a variable by it's name, and as a property of the `window` object: `window.jQuery`.

What libraries do by default if you include them with `<script>` tag is define themselves as a global variable. So with Backbone.js you will have `Backbone` global variable defined for you, and it will be available as `window.Backbone`, because `window` is the global object.

Similarly, Angular will define `angular` global variable, Zepto will define `Zepto`, and so on.

For this reason you should be able to detect any library by the global variables it defines.

A caveat however, is that in modern javascript applications, libraries do not necessarily register a global variable. They may be defined within a scope (a function) of that application. For this reason checking `window.Libraryname` doesn't guarantee the page isn't using this library. And in fact it may be a very difficult task to detect a library in this case.

1. There are too many frameworks/libraries, so it is up on you to create the list, or find anyone who maintains one. Then you would look into what global variables that framework defines, so you could look for them as the identifier of that framework.
2. As I explained above, `angular` is the global variable, also available as `window.angular`. If you create a scoped `angular` variable, like `function (){ var angular = "my angular"; }`, you will still be able to get the global one with `window.angular`.
3. It is possible that the maintainers of that code became aware of two or more libraries that define `Backbone` global variable. And only the Backbone we know about, includes the `sync` function. That might be the reason they additionally check that `Backbone.sync` is a function. They can't just check for the `Backbone.sync` function without checking for `Backbone` first, because on non-backbone pages that would cause error.
   Similarly, with Underscore, there might be many libraries that define global `_` variable, so we can know for sure it is the Underscore library by checking one of it's methods in work.
4. As I mentioned above, libraries will not necessarily define a global variable, in which case you will not be able to detect them automatically. As an example, in a modern javascript application, you could use a library as a dependency with [Browserify](http://browserify.org/), or [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/), in which case the library most likely will not register any global variables.

Comment: I’m actually looking for an updated answer on this.